# Python Window Resize

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

Using Python + PyGTK.
Is there a signal/event way of checking for a window resize? If so then what is the easiest way of implementing and using this signal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

a [`gtk.Window`](http://library.gnome.org/devel/pygtk/stable/class-gtkwindow.html) is also a [`gtk.Container`](http://library.gnome.org/devel/pygtk/stable/class-gtkcontainer.html), so it answers to the [`check-resize`](http://library.gnome.org/devel/pygtk/stable/class-gtkcontainer.html#signal-gtkcontainer--check-resize) signal.

Here's minimal sample code:

```
import gtk

def changed(window):
    print 'I have resized.'

w = gtk.Window()
w.connect('check-resize', changed)
w.show()
gtk.main()
```